# Inserting a certificate into the keychain

Tags: c, macos, security, ssl, core-foundation

I have a client that retrieves a certificate (.pfx), including a private key, from a server and I add this to the local keychain with the following code: -

```
void AddCertToKeyChain(const QByteArray& cert, const QString& password)
{
    SecKeychainRef keyChain = nil;

    OSStatus err = SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault(kSecPreferencesDomainUser, &keyChain);
    if (err != errSecSuccess)
    {
        emit Log("Failed to access system keychain: " + LogMessageForStatus(err));
        return;
    }

    SecExternalFormat format = kSecFormatPKCS12;
    SecExternalItemType itemType = kSecItemTypeAggregate;
    SecItemImportExportFlags flags = 0;

    SecItemImportExportKeyParameters params;
    memset(&params, 0, sizeof(params));

    params.version = SEC_KEY_IMPORT_EXPORT_PARAMS_VERSION;
    params.flags = 0;
    params.passphrase = password.toCFString();

    params.alertTitle = NULL;
    params.alertPrompt = NULL;
    params.accessRef = NULL;

    // create and populate the key usage array
    CFMutableArrayRef keyUsage = CFArrayCreateMutable(
            kCFAllocatorDefault,
            0,
            &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks
        );

    CFArrayAppendValue(keyUsage, kSecAttrCanEncrypt);
    CFArrayAppendValue(keyUsage, kSecAttrCanDecrypt);
    CFArrayAppendValue(keyUsage, kSecAttrCanDerive);
    CFArrayAppendValue(keyUsage, kSecAttrCanSign);
    CFArrayAppendValue(keyUsage, kSecAttrCanVerify);
    CFArrayAppendValue(keyUsage, kSecAttrCanWrap);
    CFArrayAppendValue(keyUsage, kSecAttrCanUnwrap);

    keyUsage = NULL; // Error without this - Failed to import certificate: The key usage mask is not supported.

    // create and populate the key attributes array
    CFMutableArrayRef keyAttributes = CFArrayCreateMutable(
            kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks
        );

    // required for import
    params.keyUsage = keyUsage;
    params.keyAttributes = keyAttributes;

    OSStatus status = SecItemImport(cert.toCFData(), CFSTR(".p12"), &format, &itemType, flags, &params, keyChain, NULL);
    if(status == errSecSuccess)
        emit Log("Certificate successfully imported");
    else
    {
        emit Log("Failed to import certificate: " + LogMessageForStatus(status));
    }
}
```

The certificate and private key appear in the keychain, as expected.

However, trying to retrieve the certificate is a problem, either programmatically or using the Keychain application.

If I select to export the private key from the keychain, I'm provided with the following error in a dialog: -

> **"An error has occurred. Unable to export an item. The contents of this item cannot be retrieved"**

However, if the certificate and key are added to the keychain by double-clicking on the pfx, exporting the key works as expected.

So, why would the code above cause the problem of not being able to export the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assistance of Quinn at Apple, It seems that the method described in the question should work, but doesn't.

Using an old CDSA style flag instead does in fact work, doing something like this: -

```
OSStatus                            err;
SecExternalFormat                   format;
SecItemImportExportKeyParameters    params;

params.version = SEC_KEY_IMPORT_EXPORT_PARAMS_VERSION;
params.flags = 0;
params.passphrase = (__bridge CFStringRef) pkcs12Password;
params.alertTitle = NULL;
params.alertPrompt = NULL;
params.accessRef = NULL;
params.keyUsage = NULL;
params.keyAttributes = (__bridge CFArrayRef) @[ @(CSSM_KEYATTR_EXTRACTABLE) ];

format = kSecFormatPKCS12;
err = SecItemImport(
    (__bridge CFDataRef) pkcs12Data, 
    CFSTR("p12"), 
    &format, 
    NULL, 
    0, 
    &params, 
    keychain, 
    NULL
);
```

Note the setting of params.keyAttributes, which defines the key to be extractable.

Alternatively, the older (deprecated) SecKeychainItemImport API may be used: -

```
BOOL                            success;
OSStatus                        err;
NSArray *                       result;
SecExternalFormat               format;
SecKeyImportExportParameters    params;
CFArrayRef                      importedItems;

result = nil;
importedItems = NULL;

format = kSecFormatPKCS12;
memset(&params, 0, sizeof(params));
params.passphrase = password;
params.keyAttributes = CSSM_KEYATTR_EXTRACTABLE;

err = SecKeychainItemImport(
   (CFDataRef) pkcs12Blob,     // importedData
   NULL,                       // fileNameOrExtension
   &format,                    // inputFormat
   NULL,                       // itemType
   0,                          // flags
   &params,                    // keyParams
   self->keychain,             // importKeychain
   &importedItems              // outItems
);
success = (err == noErr);
```

While the function SecKeychainItemImport is defined as deprecated in Apple's documentation, I have been informed that it's unlikely to be removed any time soon.